# Call function in from another class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

my proplem is : I have function `LoadTaskList()` on `MainActivity` , but in CustomAdapter i called `LoadTaskList()` but it doesn't active

CustomAdapter.cs

```
       public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mainActivity.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, null);

            TextView txtTask = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.task_title);
            Button btnDelete = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDelete);


            txtTask.Text = taskList[position];

            btnDelete.Click += delegate {
                string task = taskList[position];
                dbHelper.deleteTask(task);

                mainActivity.LoadTaskList(); // here
            };
            return view;
        }
```

MainActivity.cs

```
   public void LoadTaskList()
    {
        List<string> taskList = dbHelper.getTaskList();
        if (mAdapter == null)
        {
            mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, taskList,dbHelper);
            lstTask.Adapter = mAdapter;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This function to reload ListView , but in my case it doesn't reload ListView when you call it on CustomAdapter

Comment: is `mAdapter == null` when you call it second time? duh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

Just change LoadTaskList() to public and call it from CustomAdapter